# Handling sensitive keys django

Tags: python, django, postgresql

OS: Win 8.1
System: surface pro 3
python 2.7.9
postgre: 9.3
django 1.7.1

I am trying to complete the Ultimate Django tutorial:    https://ultimatedjango.com/learn-django/lessons/handling-sensitive-keys/?trim=yes

On the section of sensitive keys it gives me the following errors when I run the server with : python manage.py runserver

```
CommandError: You must set settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS if DEBUG is False.
```

Then on the settings.py i put :
    ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

and when I run the server again gives the following error: 
Performing system checks...

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at     
0x00000000035BD588
>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 222, in   
wrapper
fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "c:\venv\lib\site-  
packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py",
line 107, in inner_run
self.check_migrations()
File "c:\venv\lib\site-  
 packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py",
 line 159, in check_migrations
 executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
 File "c:\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 17,  
 in __init__
 self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
 File "c:\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 48,   
 in _
 _init__
 self.build_graph()
 File "c:\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 179,  
 in
 build_graph
 self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
 File "c:\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 59,  
 in
 applied_migrations
 self.ensure_schema()
 File "c:\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 49, 
 in
 ensure_schema
 if self.Migration._meta.db_table in  
 self.connection.introspection.get_table_
 list(self.connection.cursor()):
 File "c:\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\__init__.py", line 167, 
 in
 cursor
 cursor = utils.CursorWrapper(self._cursor(), self)
 File "c:\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\__init__.py", line 138,   
 in
 _cursor
self.ensure_connection()
File "c:\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\__init__.py", line 133,  
in
ensure_connection
self.connect()
File "c:\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
File "c:\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\__init__.py", line 133,  
in
ensure_connection
self.connect()
File "c:\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\__init__.py", line 122,  
in
connect
self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
File "c:\venv\lib\site- 
packages\django\db\backends\postgresql_psycopg2\base.py 
", line 134, in get_new_connection
return Database.connect(**conn_params)
File "c:\venv\lib\site-packages\psycopg2-2.6-py2.7-win-
amd64.egg\psycopg2\__in
it__.py", line 164, in connect
conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

Any help ?

Comment: Have you supplied a password for your PostgreSQL database? If so, have you tried restarting the database server?

Comment: `django.db.utils.OperationalError: fe_sendauth: no password supplied`  <- no password supplied for your database?

Comment: I did supply the password on the environment and it accepted it. Also I supplied the secret key too with the following code:    setx CRMEASY_DB_PASS <my password>; Same for the secret key; both were accepted successfully. It does work when you put the password on the setting.py files; but that was the point of the exercise to avoid doing that.

Comment: I also restart the database server multiple times. I even tried to delete and create a new Django project; but still having the same issues.